# Packaging jar with JSch with gradle

Tags: gradle, noclassdeffounderror, jsch

I'm prepare packaging my code which works with ssh using Jsch. For packaging I'm using gradle - Jsch included as compile-time dependency. 
When running

```
java -jar java_ssh.jar
```

I'm getting an

> NoClassDefFoundError on com.jcraft.jsch.JSch

exception.
Here is the gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': '<my class with main method>'
    }
}

dependencies {      
    compile 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.52'
}
```

Should I specify more info for build?
Include somehow ssh related jar in my one?
Or class path?

Answer (score 4):

In file ...\app\build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.55'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Maven, I was able to compile the JSch correctly using these lines in my gradle files.

"app" C:...\AndroidStudioProjects...\library\build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.54'
}
```

"Project" C:...\AndroidStudioProjects...\build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
    }
}
```